# getdate select statement issue in program

Tags: sql, vb.net, date, getdate

I have a `VB.net` 2010 program, using MS personal SQL server (MSDE) version 2010, where a `select` statement is failing. The query works correctly from the query tester, and the program functions properly by using other queries.

The 'requestdate' entries are `MM/DD/YYYY`, or 1/22/2014 for a recent entry.

The SQL statement is:

```
Select count(*)  from Table 
WHERE (Closed = 'false') AND (requestdate < convert(date, GETDATE() - 3));
```

I am trying to get a count of entries that are between today and 2 days ago. There there is a simular query asking for 7 days.

Any help would be great. -Thanks

Comment: Which database is used for this query execution? And in sql this is invalid syntax.

Comment: Hi,This is Microsoft personal server 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed it:

Select count(*)  from tablew WHERE    (Closed = 'false') AND (datediff(dd,requestdate,getdate()) < 3)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select count(*)  from Table 
WHERE (Closed = 'false') AND (requestdate < convert(date, GETDATE()-3));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not fix the issue.